# Handling multiple exe file execution in a WebAPI project

Tags: c#, multithreading, webapi

I have a .NET project WebAPI and one of the endpoints is calling some service that uses the chromedriver.exe file stored in the API hosting webspace. This chromedriver.exe file is added to the project and stored in a give folder on the hosting. After some investigation from this usage:

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(option))
```

I came to this:

```
 using (var process = new Process())
 {
   process.StartInfo.FileName = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "Exes\\WebRunner.exe";
             process.StartInfo.Arguments = "https://testguild.com/HpSupport.html";
   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   process.Start();
             string result = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
             process.WaitForExit();
             await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Result = {result}");
```

This "WebRunner.exe" is a console application that actually is using the chromedriver.exe like so:

```
 var path = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "chromedriver.exe";

 var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
 var newPath = path.Replace(".exe", $"{guid}.exe");
 File.Copy(path, newPath);

 var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(newPath, chromeOptions);

       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(args[0]);
 var d = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body"));
```

Problem: when I am calling my WebAPI endpoint it still waits for the first request to finish and then starts another. What I want is to call this endpoint 3 times in the row and see 3 different instances of this chromedriver.exe running.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Well written questions get answers in minutes. Alternatively, I'd suggest you copy and paste your question in to ChatGPT - it actually gave some quite good answers.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have asked ChatGPT before posting the question multiple times, I saw solutions with semaphores or locks, however with all those solutions I still run into issues (for example: the chromedriver is not being killed, thus another instances are not started). On the other hand shall we stop asking questions because we have chatGpt? I will update the question in couple of hours with some implementation example.